# Unintentional capacitive coupling

Tags: capacitor, coupling

This question comes from text from the AOE 3rd ed. It's about unintentional capacitive coupling right after differentiators in chapter 1. I've included the text. Please read the first excerpt. That is where my question is from. The second photo includes a graph Figure 1.45 that I reference.

I dont understand: “resistor termination on your signal line.” and “reduce the source resistance of the signal line.” I understand how capacitors, charge, voltage, and current, differentiators supplied DC, sin, and squarewaves so Figure 1.45 makes sense. I've written and attached a 7 page document about capacitors I'm currently working on. Would you please help me by rephrasing the parts of the text I don't understand, providing an example, and or explain like I'm five (elif). Thanks.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12gug-CDFmSIw96a-6j31GgybIcRjOr09F0q_aluErJ8/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGPQUT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

RC scope responses are like the game Snakes and Ladders.

The step number ratio to the total number of steps determines % of how high you are like the ratio of the source signal.

The snake curve of the RC differentiator is due to the RC =T time value. Normally we show a voltage generator as ideal with source R=0 but reality says it has a real  R1 value. LEt's call  R2 as the load value.

The RC value  is the initial straight slope of the snake in time has a value in seconds.

In the drawing that we call a **schematic** or a **logic diagram**,  the C1 symbol has a value with a multiplier value shown in pF which is short for picofarads and that has a value \$10^{-12} Farads\$.

Thus C*R=T= time in seconds

But R is an equivalent parallel resistance of R1,R2. This is the impedance at the output point at a high enough frequency where C becomes a short circuit.

So R=R1//R2 becomes a value slightly less than the smaller of each value.

1/(1/R1+1/R2)= 90 ohms \$[=90~\Omega]\$

Thus your differentiator, the initial slope duration could be T= 90 microseconds \$[=90 ~\mu s]\$  with these values. ( using  10kHz =1/100us period) are in a similar range.

The values chosen here were arbitrary or just a random example only.

That means that the total steps on the ladder are 100 +900 = 1000 so that output step is 900/1000= 90% near the top or 10% down which matches the attenuation of the sig generator output.

By making the **source impedance much smaller** *relative to the load* gets you closer to the full signal source level or the top of the ladder.

[Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%206.450009306485578%2050%205%2050%0Ac%20400%2048%20400%20160%200%201e-8%20-0.47030008851894967%0Ar%20400%20160%20400%20288%200%2050%0AO%20400%20160%20512%20160%200%0Ag%20400%20288%20400%20320%200%0Ac%20400%20160%20288%20160%200%200.00001%20-4.786146559135382%0AR%20240%20160%20192%20160%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%20400%2016%20400%20-16%200%202%20400%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20288%20160%20240%20160%200%2050%0Ar%20400%2048%20400%2016%200%201500%0Ao%202%2016%200%2012290%200.7428340466641606%200.0001%200%201%20out%0Ah%203%201%200%0A) of your spikey sine wave using a differentiator (Snake and ladder circuit)

[image]

Comment: Thanks tony!!! :))))))))))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 220volt 60Hz power cable, 10 centimeters from a 10 centimeter by 1mm signal trace. The signal trace has 20pF capacitance and is 100,000 ohms resistance, both R and C are shunting to Ground.

Lets use the parallel-plate capacitive model to predict the coupling capacitance.

C = E0* Er * Area/Distance.

C~~ 9e-12 Farad/meter * (1mm * 10cm)/ 10cm) = 9e-12 * 1mm/1meter = 9e-15 ~~ 1e-14 Farad

I = C * dV/dT = 1e-14Farad * (220 * 377 volt//second)

I = 1e-14 * (200 * 400) = 1e-14 * 80,000 = 8*10^(-14+4)

I ~~ 8e-10 ~~ 1e-9 == 1 nanoAmpere (we assume the Cstray sets impedance and current.

Our circuit is high pass filter. The corner has TAU = R*C = 100Kohm * 20pF = 2uS.

The corner frequency is (1 / 2uS) * (1/6.28) = 500,000 / 6.28 = 90,000 Hz.

Our frequency is 60 Hz (ignoring any spikes etc on the power line)

What is the voltage? (1nanoAmp * 100Kohm) * (60 Hz / 90,000 Hz)

1e-4 volts * (1/1500) = 66 nanoVolts.

The 66 nanoVolts is because the interfering signal is  PURE SIN.

Not spikes on it, such as motors or switchregs or fluorescent-lights cause.

Here is the circuit I've used

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvIdmc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOW ---suppose your interfering signal is 220 volts * 1.414 peak-rectified into DC, thus 300+ volts, and chopped in a switching-regulator with 30 nanosecond edges. The dV/dT is 10 Billion volts per second, compared to 80,000 volts per second, or 10^+10 versus 10^+5. Thus the current (its the displacement current, thru the current is 100,000X higher.

And the Capacitive Divider? Just the ratio of 10fF to 20pF.